# React map gl NavigationControls not showing on page

Tags: react-map-gl

I think it might be a css issue, the docs state: Like its Mapbox counterpart, this control relies on the mapbox-gl stylesheet to work properly. Make sure to add the stylesheet to your page. What stylesheet would this be exactly?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactMapGL, { Marker, Popup, NavigationControl } from 'react-map-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import env from '../env';

const NFTMapLayoutOne = () => {
    const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
        latitude: 38.57,
        longitude: -121.47,
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh',
        zoom: 1,
    });


    const navControlStyle = {
        right: 100,
        top: 200,
    };

    const geoSuccess = (pos) => {
        let crd = pos.coords;

        setViewport({
            latitude: crd.latitude,
            longitude: crd.longitude,
            width: '100vw',
            height: '100vh',
            zoom: 8,
        });


    const nearMeHandler = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <ReactMapGL
                {...viewport}
                mapboxApiAccessToken={env.MAPBOX_TOKEN}
                onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewport(viewport)}
            >
                <NavigationControl style={navControlStyle} />
            </ReactMapGL>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NFTMapLayoutOne;
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent half a day figuring this out. The react-map-gl really needs to update its documentation. Such a pain trying to figure out something so trivial. Even their own documentation doesn't specify importing the .css library is required to make the controls appear on the map frame. Anyway, this seemed to work for me. Hope it helps!

`import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';`

Comment: It´s works perfect for me! I use next.js 14 with app directory

Answer (score 0):

The docs shows this:

```
<NavigationControl style={navControlStyle} />
```

In order to actually show on the page I wrapped it in a div

```
<div style={navControlStyle}>
    <NavigationControl />
</div>
```